# $B$ is an $A$-algebra. If $y\in B$ is integral then $\varphi(A)[y]$ is finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-homomorphism

> Let $B$ be an $A$-algebra. (That is, $\varphi:A\to B$). Suppose $y\in B$ zeroes a normalized polynomial $0\ne f\in A[x]$. (That is, $y$ is integral in $A$). Show that $L:=\varphi(A)[y]$ is finite above $A$. ($L$ is closure of $\{\varphi(a):a\in A\}\cup\{y\}$ under $+,-,\cdot$).

In the solution:

Let $$0\ne x^n+c_{n-1}x^{n-1} +\dots+c_0\in A[x]$$
which zeroed in $y$. Then 
$$
0=y^n+\varphi(c_{n-1})y^{n-1}+\dots+\varphi(c_0)
$$
But I don't understand the last equlity. I guess that the meaning is that 
$$
0=\varphi (0)=\varphi(f(y))
\\=\varphi (y^n+c_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\dots+c_0)
\\=\varphi(y)^n+\varphi(c_{n-1})\varphi(y^{n-1})+\dots+\varphi(c_0)
$$
But the last transition is not valid since $\varphi(y)$ is not defined! ($y\notin A =\text{Domain}(\varphi)$).

I would like for an explanation, thanks in adence.

Comment: What you call "complete" is normally called "integral". Are you translating from Russian?

Comment: The right transloation indeed is *integral*. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

To evaluate a polynomial $f\in A[x]$ at a point $y\in B$, one uses the universal property of the polynomial ring: there is a unique homomorphism $\bar\varphi_y: A[x] \to B$ with $\bar\varphi_y|_A=\varphi$ and $\bar\varphi_y(x)=y$. Then, one usually writes $f(y)=\bar\varphi(f)$. Consequently,
$$
0 = f(y) = \bar\varphi_y(f) = y^n + \varphi(c_{n-1})y^{n-1}+\cdots+\varphi(c_0).
$$

Comment: I don't quite understand the transition $f(y)=\bar\varphi(f)$. We have indeed:
$$
f(y)=y^n+c_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\dots+c_0
\\=\bar\varphi(x)^n+c_{n-1}\bar\varphi(x)^{n-1}+\dots+c_0
$$
But
$$
\bar\varphi(f(x))=\bar\varphi(x)^n+\bar\varphi(c_{n-1})\bar\varphi(x)^{n-1}+\dots+\bar\varphi(c_0)
$$
So why does $\forall i,\ c_i=\bar\varphi(c_i)$?

Comment: Dear @J.Doe, do not let yourself get confused by the abusive notation $c_{n-k}\cdot y^k$ - if you insist on spelling out the morphism $\varphi$, then there is no such thing. There is only $\varphi(c_{n-k})\cdot y^k$, which is the same as $\bar\varphi_y(c_{n-k})\cdot y^k$ by assumption.